# Path for JDK8 installation on RPI not working

Tags: java, unix, raspberry-pi

I have tried to upgrade my existing JDK8 on my Raspberry Pi, but I failed.

I downloaded the ARM version from the oracle site, extracted it in Windows, transferred it to my pi via FTP and copied it to /usr/local.

Then I tried to link the folder to $PATH or update-alternatives, but the terminal and tomcat will not recognize I have java installed.

I know you have to edit bash.bashrc, environment or profile to edit the PATH for every boot, but this does not even work in the same session.

[image: Terminal commands]

**Update:**

I solved my problem on my own now somehow...

I reinstalled the OS completely and followed some tutorial to update jdk, again.
Downloaded, unzipped, chmod, set PATH and JAVA_HOME, set update-alternatives and this time it worked somehow...

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/local/jdk8/bin
sudo chmod +x java
```

Comment: I think I already tried that too, it would still say 'java: command not found'. Anyway I solved it somehow now, I'm updating my first post.